# BigQuery “This query will process 0 B when run” for _PARTITIONDATE

Tags: google-bigquery

For a query like this:

```
select _PARTITIONDATE, count(*) from mydataset.mytable group by 1
```

BigQuery displays "This query will process 0 B when run", even though it processes many rows.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

_PARTITIONDATE and _PARTITIONTIME are pseudo columns and no columns with actual data. Query processed doesn't bill for any data.

Check the Job Information in UI to verify the Bytes billed is 0B.

Answer (score 0):

your this particular query is getting answered from metadata tables, hence no cost. If you use some filter condition or use some actual column in the group by, you will incur cost.